# Issue passing an array of document into another document node JS mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema, crud

---

I have some issues using Schemas in MongoDB and NodeJS:

I have two Schemas, each one is in a file.js. The first one (pasted here) contains an array of the second.

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const installationSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  }],
  // Array of services
  services: [{
    name: String,
  }],
  // Array of sensors
  sensors: [{
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'SensorSchema'
  }]

})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Installation', installationSchema)
```

Things are that when I create manually an array of SensorSchema to push it into the installationSchema, once in MongoDB I only see an array of ObjectID, meanwhile the other arrays have both ObjectId an String values..
What i find strange is that tha the array i used to temporaly stock the SensorSchema works fine when console-loged.

### What I see in MongoDB:

```
> db.installations.find().pretty()                                               
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60813e8ca4718487d91f8a37"),
        "sensors" : [
                ObjectId("60813e8ca4718487d91f8a40"),
                ObjectId("60813e8ca4718487d91f8a41"),
                ObjectId("60813e8ca4718487d91f8a42")
        ],
        "name" : "Test",
        "equipments" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("60813e8ca4718487d91f8a38"),
                        "name" : "Equip1"
                }
        ],
        "services" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("60813e8ca4718487d91f8a39"),
                        "name" : "Service1"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("60813e8ca4718487d91f8a3a"),
                        "name" : "Service2"
                }
        ],
```

---

### My array displayed in console:

```
[
  {
    _id: 60813e8ca4718487d91f8a40,
    name: 'Termometer',
    tag: 'T-R1/12',
    range: '-5ºC / 140ºC ±2ºC'
  },
  {
    _id: 60813e8ca4718487d91f8a41,
    name: 'Manometer',
    tag: 'P-R1/12',
    range: '70mbar / PATM ±15mbar'
  },
  {
    _id: 60813e8ca4718487d91f8a42,
    name: 'Tacometer',
    tag: 'V-R1/12',
    range: '5-100 RPM ±10%'
  }
]
```

---

What do I miss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out a mix of each answer, and what finnally worked is this :

```
// Array of sensors
  sensors: []
```

The array is not declared as an SensorSchema but an empty one, and  works fine in MongoDB.
Thanks for your help Dhaval !

Answer (score 0):

### Try like this.

```
//IMPORT SensorSchema HERE
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const installationSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  }],
  // Array of services
  services: [{
    name: String,
  }],
  // Array of sensors
  sensors: [{
    type: SensorSchema
    default: {}
  }]

})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Installation', installationSchema)
```

Comment: If it's work fine with your requirement then please mark answer with useful, 
Thank You !

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I'v already tried this way and it makes the app crash.

I tried [SensorSchema], [sensorSchema], just got an app crash.

Adding const SensorSchema = require('./models/SensorSchema') gives me an message of : Error: Cannot find module './models/SensorSchema'

Comment: What's your requirements?

Comment: For now, I would like the object "installation" to contain an array of "sensorSchema", and to save it into MongoDB. For now, only the ObjectId are displayed in MongoDB, and using Compass I did not find the SensorSchema in my collection..

Comment: can you share your `SensorSchema` file structure, as per your second last edited comment, i can check.

Comment: Sure, here it goes : const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema


const sensorSchema = new Schema(
  {name: String,
  tag: String,
  range: String}
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('SensorSchema', sensorSchema)

Comment: I've edited `sensors` field in `installationSchema` definition in my answer, try like that